# can´t access list attribute in asp net mvc 4 view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Might be simple but can´t find why

I cannot access list attributes in my view:

As you can see, I have a class that contains a list of RelacionamentoNomeadoModel class
**Model:**

```
    public class RelacionamentoNomeadoModel
    {
        public int idRelacionamento { get; set; }
        public string nomeTipoRight { get; set; }
        public string nomeTipoLeft { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelacionamentoListModel
    {
        public List<RelacionamentoNomeadoModel> lista { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I build the model and populate the RelacionamentoNomeadoModel  class to later add it to the class containing the List
**Controller**

```
var relacionamentoObj = from r in context.sistema_relacionamento
                                        join d in context.sistema_DocType on r.idTipoLeft equals d.id
                                        select new tgpwebged.Models.SettingsModels.RelacionamentoNomeadoModel
                                        {
                                           idRelacionamento = r.id,
                                           nomeTipoLeft = d.tipoName,
                                           nomeTipoRight = d.tipoName
                                        };

                return PartialView(relacionamentoObj.ToList());
```

And the last I am trying to acces rela.lista.idRelacionamento  or any other property.
I am able to access them from the controller bu not after I pass to the view
**View**

```
   @{
    List<tgpwebged.Models.SettingsModels.RelacionamentoListModel> relacionamentos = Model;

    foreach(var rela in relacionamentos) {
    rela.lista.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing to the View a collection of `RelacionamentoNomeadoModel` objects, while in the view you expect that the Model be a collection of `tgpwebged.Models.SettingsModels.RelacionamentoListModel`.
Don't know why you need `RelacionamentoListModel` class, but I think that if you use this code will be working fine:

```
@{
    List<RelacionamentoNomeadoModel> relacionamentos = Model;

    foreach(var rela in relacionamentos) {
       // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data to the View as a strongly typed model so you will need to add below line to your view:

```
     @model ProjectName.Models.YourModelName
```